# Getting Event Handler from Instance of Class

Tags: vb.net

I'm just getting started with custom classes so I wrote a button strip. It inherits a panel and populates it with buttons from strings passed to my `.Add()`.

```
ButtonStrip1.Add("Button","Texts","Go Here")
```

I'd like for it to be able to naturally grab `ButtonStrip1.Click`'s handler and pass it on to child buttons and delete it from ButtonStrip1.

I haven't been able to figure that out, so I've been doing

```
Public Class ButtonStrip
    Inherits Panel
    Public Property Innermargin As Integer = 5
    Dim Offset As Integer = Innermargin
    Dim Buttons = New List(Of ButtonStrip_Button)
    Dim StoredFN As EventHandler

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Function Add(fn As EventHandler, ParamArray ByVal Values As String())
        StoredFN = fn
        For Each V In Values
            Dim B As New ButtonStrip_Button
            Buttons.Add(B)
            Me.Controls.Add(B)
            B.Text = V
            B.Left = Offset + Innermargin
            B.Top = Innermargin

            Offset = B.Left + B.Width
            AddHandler B.Click, fn
        Next
        RemoveHandler Me.Click, fn
        Me.Width = Offset + Innermargin
        Me.Height = Buttons(0).height + Innermargin * 2
    End Function

    Function Add(ParamArray ByVal Values As String())
        If StoredFN Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("First Add() must supply a function")
        End If
        Me.Add(StoredFN, Values)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ButtonStrip_Button
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Public Sub New()
        AutoSize = True
        AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    End Sub
End Class
```

which is called by

```
ButtonStrip1.Add(AddressOf ButtonStrip1_Click,"Button","Texts","Go Here")
```

What I'd basically like to do is (psuedo-code)

```
Function Add(fn As EventHandler, ParamArray ByVal Values As String())
    If StoredFN is Nothing Then StoredFN = Me.Click
        ...
        AddHandler B.Click, Me.Click
    Next
    RemoveHandler Me.Click, Me.Click
    ...
End Function
```

I've tried changing a few things and googled a lot. I've also tried using `CallByName(Me,"Click",CallType.Method)` and with `CallType.Get`, but the error I get is `Expression 'Click' is not a procedure, but occurs as the target of a procedure call.` It also returns this exact same message for unhandled events, such as ButtonStrip1 has no `MouseDown` Event.

I've also tried using `MyClass`.

Not seen here is an alternative `.Add()` that add `StoredFN` to `B.click`

For instance, this click event works with my code

```
Private Sub ButtonStrip1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStrip1.Click
    msgbox("You clicked " & sender.text & ".")
End Sub
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is wrong. There's no way that you should be getting one of the child `Button` controls as the `sender` in the `Click` event handler of the `ButtonStrip`. Any and every event for an object should be passing that object to the `sender` of its event handlers. What you should be doing is adding a new `ButtonClicked` event to your `ButtonStrip` and passing the `Button` that was clicked as a property of the `e` parameter.  If you want to go that way, which you should, then I will provide an answer that shows how.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I updated my question to include the class's full code. sender.text is working to give me the button labels in VS 2015. ... Anyway, I would absolutely appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was suggesting was something like this:

```
Public Class ButtonStrip
    Inherits Panel

    Public Event ButtonClick As EventHandler(Of ButtonClickEventArgs)

    Protected Overridable Sub OnButtonClick(e As ButtonClickEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ButtonClick(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        OnButtonClick(New ButtonClickEventArgs(DirectCast(sender, Button)))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(ParamArray values As String())
        Dim btn As New Button

        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Buttons_Click

        '...
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class ButtonClickEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public ReadOnly Property Button As Button

    Public Sub New(button As Button)
        Me.Button = button
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now there's no need to pass event handlers around.  When a `Button` is clicked, the `ButtonStrip` handles that event and then raises its own `ButtonClick` event.  Neither the `ButtonStrip` nor the `Buttons` have to care about any methods that handle that event as it will be handled the same way any other event is.  In a form, you'd then handle the `ButtonClick` event of the `ButtonStrip` and get the `Button` that was clicked from `e.Button`.  You could also add an `Index` property if you wanted to know the position of the `Button` rather than the `Button` itself.